# WPF MenuItem Delimiter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menuitem

What is the simplest way to put a little delimiter/line between 2 menu items in WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put a Separator between the MenuItems.

Answer (score 5):

```
<MenuItem Header="Item 1" IsCheckable="true"/>
<Separator/>
<MenuItem Header="Item 2" IsCheckable="true">
```